# How to pass data between two cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

After hours of googling it seems that I need a hint from society.

So the problem is:
I have two custom prototype cells. First one contains `UICollectionView` with 12 cells, second one contains only a label.

My task is to pass `indexPath.row` from that `collectionView` from first cell to the label from the second cell.

`didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` not working or I didn't tuned it properly.

Any ideas on how to implement will be very appreciated!

Here's my code  (sorry for poor StackOverflow formatting)

```
    import UIKit

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    var storedOffsets = [Int: CGFloat]()


    var descrLabel = UILabel()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

            let bgImg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background"))
            bgImg.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.backgroundView = bgImg
            return cell
        }

        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DescriptionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DescriptionTableViewCell

            cell.descriptionLabel.text = self.descrLabel.text
            return cell
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        guard let tableViewCell = cell as? MainTableViewCell else { return }

        tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
        tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        guard let tableViewCell = cell as? MainTableViewCell else { return }

        storedOffsets[indexPath.row] = tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset
    }
}


extension MainTableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MainCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell
         return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Collection view at row \(collectionView.tag) selected index path \(indexPath.row)")
        self.descrLabel.text = "testText"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us some relevant code that you have.

Comment: @user3351949 yes, sure

Answer (score 0):

I played around in playground and made this.
It's not tested, but it should give you idea.

```
  protocol CustomDelegate{
    func passData(data: AnyObject)
}

class CustomColletionView : UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate{
    var customDelegate : CustomDelegate!
    func didSelectItemAtIndexPath(collectionView : UICollectionView, indexPath : NSIndexPath){
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        let someData = ""
        customDelegate.passData(someData)
    }
}
class ViewController: UITableViewController, CustomDelegate{
    var labelCellData : AnyObject?{
        didSet{
            //reloadCell when data is received
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
        }
    }
    func passData(data: AnyObject) {
        labelCellData = data
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"Indetifier1")
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "simpleCell")
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row{
        case 0:
            //this should contain CustomCollectionView
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Indetifier1") as! CustomTableViewCell
            cell.collectionView.customDelegate = self
            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("simpleCell")
            cell?.textLabel?.text = labelCellData as? String
            return cell!
        default:
            break
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var collectionView : CustomColletionView!
    // You need to implement it

}
```

Comment: thank you for the response!
Actually i found the solution, and it is simple as hell: I just need to call `tableView.reloadData()` every time I call `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`and that's it :)